# SSRS: Report border should not been displayed in Report Viewer

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report created in SSRS 2008 that I call from and display in an asp page using the Report Viewer Control. In the Report Viewer my report has border surrounding the charts, i would like to disable this border completely and make it only the charts to be shown. i tried using border size default as "none", but i am able to see the border in report viewer.Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

First, set border style as "None" and try viewing the report.

If this does not work, then change the color of the border and see if it changes the color of the border in the asp.net page. If not, it is probably the "Body" border that you are seeing (the white dotted part in design view). Make sure these are all set to None for border.

If that does not work, it is most likely a container that has a border setting by default or explicitly stated in your asp.net page.